# What will happen if you don't close a socket before os._exit()?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, network-programming

As the title.
What will happen if you don't call socket.close() before os._exit() ?

Comment: That really depends on the OS, but generally most systems (like e.g. Windows or Linux or macOS) would close the socket for you. Personally I make it a habit of cleaning up after myself though, before exiting my program.

Comment: If it is Windows the connection will be reset, otherwise it will be closed properly. Don't let this happen. Close it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very OS dependent. Mostly you should be fine if you don’t close it, as most OSs do it automatically, but it is considered a best practice to close your sockets before you terminate the program.